# Alternative of Total Commander's function Synchronize directories for Synology NAS Samba and NTFS external HDD

Tags: hard-drive, samba, ntfs, sync, nas

Is there an application that has Total Commander's function "Synchronize directories" and that is 100% working and reliable on Synology NAS samba network share?

I am using it on Windows Total Commander to synchronize between Synology NAS and external hard drive connected to PC by USB 3.0.

**External drive has NTFS.** Would it be reliable on Linux?

(Unfortunately there is not good reliable synchronize function on Synology NAS.)

Comment: Krusader has a synchronization function similar to Total Commander's. But any application will only be as reliable as your filesystem/network/whatever connection.